# Why do I get an undefined error when I try to read or assign a structure field?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a submit function on the form:

```
type UserSubmitData = {
  username: string
  password: string
}

async function onSubmit(data: UserSubmitData){
    (async() => {
      const response = await getToken(data);
      console.log("response: ",response)
      if (response) {
        const accessToken = response.accessToken
        console.log(accessToken)
        saveAuth(accessToken)
      }
    })();
  }
```

Also a function that makes a request to the server and receives tokens from it:

```
const getToken = async (userData:UserSubmitData) =>{
    return postRequest<TokenResponse>("auth/login",userData).then(r => r.data)
    .catch(error => {   
      if (error.response.status === 400){
        setError("root",{type:'custom',message:"wrong username or password"})
      }else{
        setError("root",{type:'custom',message:"internal server error"})
      }
    });
  }
```

The response type:

```
type TokenResponse = {
  accessToken:string
  refreshToken:string
  loggedIn:string
}
```

Now it turns out that when the request is executed I get this `const response: void | TokenResponse`type of response.

To get rid of it, I do an `if` check and want to pull out the access token. But now I get an `undefined` error when reading the fields of the structure.That is, the response comes normal and contains 2 tokens, but in this line

```
 const accessToken = response.accessToken
```

The value is already `undefined`.

I have not encountered this yet, so I thought that there might be an incorrect `if` check, but if i remove it, nothing will change. Then what is the error that the `response` comes normal, but I can't read its fields?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to read values from an the response when it happens to be or undefined ?

to read values from a potentially undefined object, you can use optional chaining.

```
 const accessToken = response?.accessToken
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Maybe there is some other issue? I am also wondering what the console is showing you for the console.log(response). By the way: is there a reason why you wrapped the onSubmit function body into an self invoked async function? It makes the code harder to read.

Comment: @Sudhir doesn't work, undefined instead of the field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, there seems to be a mismatch relating to the response model. Your console is showing you this log:

```
response:  {access_token: '...', refresh_token: '...', logged_in: 'true'}
```

But your model defines its keys like this:

```
type TokenResponse = {
  accessToken:string //<---- this needs to be adjusted
  refreshToken:string //<---- this needs to be adjusted
  loggedIn:string //<---- this needs to be adjusted
}
```

I would suggest adjusting the TokenResponse type like this:

```
  type TokenResponse = {
    access_token:string 
    refresh_token:string
    logged_in:string
  }
```

So the final code should look like this:

```
async function onSubmit(data: UserSubmitData){
      const response = await getToken(data);
      console.log("response: ",response)
      if (response) {
        const accessToken = response.access_token
        console.log(accessToken)
        saveAuth(accessToken)
      }     
  }
```